# mar file generation in MDC

Tags: firefox, build, build-process, mdc

I am trying to [generate complete.mar file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner/Application_Update), in firefox build. when I try to generate complete.mar file, the following error occurs.

Sathi@HREF-22F4E8F33B /c/href/FF-5.1/tools/update-packaging
$ sh make_full_update.sh complete.mar new
/c/href/FF-5.1/tools/update-packaging/new /c/href/FF-5.1/tools/update-packaging
precomplete file is missing!

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answers that helped you, see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

From http://old.nabble.com/Problem-creating-MAR-file.-td32154053.html:

> That file is generated as part of the build process. If you need to
>   generate it manually you can cd into the root directory where the
>   files you are creating the complete mar are located and run the
>   createprecomplete.py python script.